# How can I get the index from the elasticsearch highlight?

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I get the index from the elasticsearch highlight?
(index is array index. 
value = ["a", "a b", "a b c", "a b c d", "a b c d e", "a b c d e f"]. 
value[4] is "a b c d e".)

Elasticsearch version is 6.4.3

create document and search with highlight
(First create a Document and apply highlighting to search.)

```
    post noritest/doc
    {
      "name": ["na", "nb", "nc", "nd", "ne", "nf"],
      "value": ["a", "a b", "a b c", "a b c d", "a b c d e", "a b c d e f"]
    }

    get noritest/_search
    {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "value": "e"
        }
      },
      "highlight" : {

            "no_match_size": 150 ,
            "require_field_match": "false", 
            "pre_tags" : ["<em>"], "post_tags" : ["</em>"],
            "fragment_size" : 150,

            "fields" : {
                "value": {}
            }
        }
    }
```

result is 
(I want to get the index of the element in the result. However, the index of the element is not included in the result.)

```
{
  "took": 0,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.39556286,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "noritest",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "wj_5jWwBGmBhVrTXpU",
        "_score": 0.39556286,
        "_source": {
          "name": [
            "na",
            "nb",
            "nc",
            "nd",
            "ne",
            "nf"
          ],
          "value": [
            "a",
            "a b",
            "a b c",
            "a b c d",
            "a b c d e",
            "a b c d e f"
          ]
        },
        "highlight": {
          "value": [
            "a b c d <em>e</em>",
            "a b c d <em>e</em> f"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I want result is (example)

```
{
  "took": 0,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.39556286,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "noritest",
        "_type": "doc",
        "_id": "wj_5jWwBGmBhVrTXpU",
        "_score": 0.39556286,
        "_source": {
          "name": [
            "na",
            "nb",
            "nc",
            "nd",
            "ne",
            "nf"
          ],
          "value": [
            "a",
            "a b",
            "a b c",
            "a b c d",
            "a b c d e",
            "a b c d e f"
          ]
        },
        "highlight": {
          "value": [
            "a b c d <em>e</em>",
            "a b c d <em>e</em> f"
          ],
          "value.index": [
            4, 5
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Help me..

Comment: what do u mean by value of index and why its `4, 5` in your response, adding more details would help us understand your requirements better.

Comment: index is array index.
value  = ["a", "a b", "a b c", "a b  c d", "a b c d e", "a b c d e f"].
value[4] is "a b c d e".

Comment: I don't think Elasticsearch is the right tool for what you want to do. Your concept of an array is lost upon posting the documents - there is no "array index". Your array gets flattened upon indexing. You can use [nested fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) to prevent that, but even then, elasticsearch will never return an "array index" as far as I know.